# integrated windows security asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, iis

What we have:
IIS, windows auth mode,
ASP.NET application (a very simply) published on IIS
but auth pop up always appears when I try to access to application
IIS and client machines are in same domain (Active Directory)
Is it normal? What can I do to fix it?

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Comment: You could try to do some setting in IE browser Add the address to the list of trusted websites and specify Automatic logon with a current user name and password in User Authentication -> Logon in Trusted Zones Sites settings. [image](https://i.imgur.com/HuAx4eP.jpg).

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me. still windows prompts to enter credentials

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to see into the requests/responses, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/11/22/troubleshooting-authentication-with-fiddler/ Before you know more about such details, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: i've just added group from AD into folder security in server - and it works